# Why are there (load byte unsigned) and (load byte) instructions in MIPS but only (store byte)?

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture

There is only a store byte instruction, so I don't get it why there are both load byte  and load byte unsigned...

I tried looking for it but couldn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

MIPS registers are 32 bits wide.  When you load a single 8-bit byte into one of those registers from memory, you have to decide whether to sign-extend it or not.  Hence the two load instructions.  When storing, there's no such ambiguity.

A loading example:

```
.data

variable: .byte 0x80

.text

lb  $t0, variable
lbu $t1, variable
```

After this code runs, `t0` will be `0xffffff80` (-128), and `t1` will be `0x00000080` (128).